# Module Federation: How to have multiple instance of the same remoteEntry file

Tags: angular, graphql, webpack-5, webpack-module-federation

I have used module federation in Angular 12 with GraphQL integration in the below pattern

1. Child2: Consists of two different modules(a and b) which are exposes to other mfes
2. Child1: Consumes 1 of the module(a) of Child2 and exposes module of its own
3. Mfe_Parent: Consumes both Child1 and Child2(with module(b))

To overcome cache busting, I've used timestamp as queryparam along with remotePaths
**In Parent Mfe_Parent**:

```
const todayTs = new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        new ModuleFederationPlugin({
            remotes: {
                "child1": `child1@https://child1.com/child1RemoteEntry.js?v=${todayTs}`,
                "child2": `child2@https://child2.com/child2RemoteEntry.js?v=${todayTs}`,
            },
       })
]};
```

**In Child1 Mfe**:

```
const todayTs = new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        new ModuleFederationPlugin({
            remotes: {
                "child2": `child2@https://child2.com/child2RemoteEntry.js?v=${todayTs}`,
            },
       })
]};
```

So with this approach the timestamp "todayTs" used will be the same while build and there will be only 1 instance of child2 is created which will be consumed by both Mfe_Parent and Child1. But with this approach if there is any change in Mfe_Parent which requires a deployment, we will still have to deploy Child1 even if there are no changes made, if not the "todayTs" will be different in both the remote paths and two instances will be created for Child2. Due to two instances created, GraphQL is not able to create two difference instance of the module from respective called mfes.

Is there any possible configuration or any way using which this dependency can be eliminated and only Mfe_Parent can be deployed without having to deploy Child1 always.